# How to implement a model on a new data set

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm new to machine learning using python. I'm trying to predict a factor lets say Price of a house, but i'm using polynomial feature of higher order degree to create a model.
So i have 2 data sets. I've prepared my model using one data set.
How to implement this model on an entirely new data set? 
I'm attaching my code below:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\experimental data/xyz1.csv", engine = 'c', dtype=float, delimiter = ",")
data2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\experimental data/xyz2.csv", engine = 'c', dtype=float, delimiter = ",")

#I have to do this step otherwise everytime i get an error of NaN or infinite value
data1.fillna(0.000, inplace=True)
data2.fillna(0.000, inplace=True)

X_train = data1.drop('result', axis = 1)
y_train = data1.result
X_test = data2.drop('result', axis = 1)
y_test = data2.result

x2_ = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False).fit_transform(X_train)
x3_ = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=False).fit_transform(X_train)

model2 = LinearRegression().fit(x2_, y_train)
model3 = LinearRegression().fit(x3_, y_train)

r_sq2 = model2.score(x2_, y_train)
r_sq3 = model3.score(x3_, y_train)

y_pred2 = model2.predict(x2_)
y_pred3 = model3.predict(x3_)
```

So basically I'm stuck after this.
How do i implement this same model on my test data to predict y_test value and compute the score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce the effect of `PolynomialFeatures`, you need to store the object itself (once for `degree=2` and again for `degree=3`.) Otherwise, you have no way to apply the fitted transform to the test dataset.

```
X_train = data1.drop('result', axis = 1)
y_train = data1.result
X_test = data2.drop('result', axis = 1)
y_test = data2.result

# store these data transform objects
pf2 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
pf3 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=False)

# then apply the transform to the training set
x2_ = pf2.fit_transform(X_train)
x3_ = pf3.fit_transform(X_train)

model2 = LinearRegression().fit(x2_, y_train)
model3 = LinearRegression().fit(x3_, y_train)

r_sq2 = model2.score(x2_, y_train)
r_sq3 = model3.score(x3_, y_train)

y_pred2 = model2.predict(x2_)
y_pred3 = model3.predict(x3_)

# now apply the fitted transform to the test set
x2_test = pf2.transform(X_test)
x3_test = pf3.transform(X_test)

# apply trained model to transformed test data
y2_test_pred = model2.predict(x2_test)
y3_test_pred = model3.predict(x3_test)

# compute the model accuracy for the test data
r_sq2_test = model2.score(x2_test, y_test)
r_sq3_test = model3.score(x3_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Then i get an error after the step- x3_test = pf3.tranform(X_test):

ValueError: X shape does not match training shape

Comment: I have no notion of the size or shape of your datasets. You'll have to make sure they have compatible dimensions, e.g. `print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape)`.

Comment: O yes, my bad! I'm so sorry! Edited that. Thank you so much for your timely help

Comment: one last question, how to calculte score, that how much my model is accurate in predicting the output for test data?

Comment: @Sukhmani I have added two lines of code at the end that mimic how you had computed the score for the training set. It's worth noting that if you have already have a vector of predicted results, running `score` will recompute all of those predictions in the background. You might want to use something like [`sklearn.metrics.r2_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score) instead.